# Spring Cloud Sleuth increased startup time

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using spring-cloud-sleuth for adding correlation id to my logs for http requests, rabbitMQ messages and sheduled events. After adding dependency app startup time increased by 50 %.
All other configuration properties like spring.sleuth.async.enabled, spring.sleuth.grpc.enabled has default value true. If I want to reduce my app startup time do I need to expicitly set all of them to false in my application properties file? (this would clog up my properties file)
Is there other ways to reduce app startup time?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to disable all of those things that you don't want to use. By default users do want to use them, that's why they are enabled.